# Does the set of isolated singularities not have limit point?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $G$ be open in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a function.

Define $D=\{z\in G: f \text{ is complex-differentiable at } z\}$

Assume that $z$ is an isolated singularity of $f$ for all $z\in G\setminus D$.

(So $f$ is somewhat weaker than meromorphic)

I have proved that $G\setminus D$ is countable and discrete. I think $D$ is open in this case, but I'm not sure how to prove this. How do I prove this?

Comment: Being analytic in a point is equivalent to have a power series expansion in around an open set. In other words, being analytic in a point is by definition being analytic in an open set that contains this point. Analyticity does not strictly makes sense for a point.

Comment: @user40276 I know that, but I'm curious whether above condition imply that $f$ analytic at a point if $f$ is complex-differentiable at a point

Comment: What's complex differentiable at a point? This does not makes sense if you do not use an open set, unless you're talking about the germ of holomorphic functions at that point.

Comment: I think I understand your claim now. I was thinking about holomorphicity. If you accept Looman-Menchof theorem this is straightforward if $f$ is continuous. But it may happens that $f$ is only complex differentiable at one point, e.g., $f(z) = |z|^2$.